# Zero the 3 lowest digits of an int

Tags: java, rounding, numerical-methods

I want to zero the 3 lowest digits of an `int`. E.g. assume my `int` is `1023`, what is the simplest and most efficient method `clearLower` such that:

```
clearLower(1023) == 1000
```

If 1000 was a power of two it would be easy to do using the bitwise "and" operator, but this is not the case. I know two possibilities:

```
public int clearLower(int a) {
    return (a/1000)*1000;
}

public int clearLower2(int a) {
    return a - a%1000;
}
```

Is there an easier and/or more efficient way?

Comment: I don't think you can find anything easier than (a/1000)*1000 or a - a%1000

Comment: Both have two operators. There is no way to do this with one operator.

Comment: @uoyilmaz which of those would be more efficient?

Comment: What if the input is not a 4-digit number?

Comment: I would think `-` and `%` is faster than `/` and `*` but it likely to be next to no difference. (a few nano-seconds at most)

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm not proposing a general solution. For my use case the numbers will always have at least 4 digits.

Comment: *At least* 4 digits is not the same. 123456 is at least 4 digits, but your code would return 123000, not 100000. You should guard against bad input: `if (a < 1000 || a > 9999) throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.valueOf(a));`

Comment: @Roland for my compiler, the instructions for both are as follows:(a/1000)*1000:
istore_1
iload_1
sipush        1000
idiv
sipush        1000
imul
istore_2


a - a%1000:
istore_1
iload_1
iload_1
sipush        1000
irem
isub
istore_2
The number of instructions are the same. I haven't check the instructions, but I guess a - a%1000 will be faster, but you will not notice it.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, +/-/*: fast, /, %: slow. Anyway, unless you use this operation in a compute-intensive portion of the code (I mean this represents 90% of what is executed - which I seriously doubt), you will never observe any effect of this nano-optimization.